# Raspberry Pi finer servo control

Tags: raspbian, servo

I'm usig RPI and Servoblaster to control servos. I've set the `--step-size to 2 us`, but I'd like to decrease it to 1us. I've tried to set the `step-size to 1us`, but the Servoblaster displays: Invalid step-size specified.

I've also tried to set the pulse width in micoseconds like `echo 1=1140us > /dev/servolaster`. It works, but it's unpredictabe (step size is set to 2us):

```
echo 1=1140us > /dev/servoblaster - motor starts spinnig
echo 1=1142us > /dev/servoblaster - motor **smoothly** speeds up
echo 1=1144us > /dev/servoblaster - motor's speed has not changed
echo 1=1146us > /dev/servoblaster - motor smoothly speeds up (OK, assume that it can be changed by +/- 4)
BUT:
echo 1=1150us > /dev/servoblaster - motor's speed has not changed - why??
echo 1=1152us > /dev/servoblaster - motor speeds up, but **fastly**
echo 1=1156us > /dev/servoblaster - motor **smoothly** speeds up
```

Motor: Turnigy aerodrive 2830-11, ESC: Turnigy Multistar 30A

Any idea?

Comment: Can your ESC (I guess, doesn't sound like a servo) resolve down to 1 microsecond.  How are you monitoring the speed change?

Comment: @joan: I'll check the ESC specs. I hear how the motor speeds up or down.

Comment: http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/ will let you send servo pulses with 1us resolution (simplest from command line is sudo pigpiod -s 1 then pigs s 4 1500 to set 1500us pulse on (Broadcom) gpio 4.  It works in the same way as servoblaster.